# Left and Right Word-Break in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, word-wrap

I would like get this behavior in Internet Explorer 11
In Chrome and Firefox the words wrap to left and right when has a flexbox center alignment. In IE11 the wrap text is only to the right. Check the pictures to see the diference in IE11.
**¿ How can get the Chrome and Firefox behavior in IE11 ?** Thanks !!

```css
div {
  width: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>The word-wrap Property</h1>

<h2>word-wrap: normal (default):</h2>
<div> This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</div>
```

[See IE11 Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOTET.png)

[See Chrome and Firefox preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaD2H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common flexbug in IE.

You could see that flex is partially supported in IE from:https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

You could also find common flexbugs and related workarounds from: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

I modified part of your code and maybe you could refer to:

CSS.

```
    .outer {
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .inner {
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

HTML.

```
<h1>The word-wrap Property</h1>
<h2>word-wrap: normal (default):</h2>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        This div contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: the running result in Chrome and IE]

Comment: Thanks Jenifer, I search the inverse result,that is, I need break the div to left and right  in IE like Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Comment: You could use F12 developer tools to check the height and width shown in Chrome.It seems that Chrome may adjust the height and width automatically but IE could not. And you could set .inner {height:72px;width: 276px;} .the result image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3x0t.png

Comment: Hi Jenifer, you may create a code snippet demo. I can't reproduce your solution, thanks !

Comment: WOW !!! Jenifer, IS THE SOLUTION, the key is use **flex-direction: column** to overcome div limits. A lot of kiss for you.

Answer (score 0):

To IE11 the solution is **use flex-direction: column;**
[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJMd7.png)